# xfoil for python package installation issues "UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'zip_save'"

Tags: python, windows, installation, pip, anaconda

On my laptop Windows 10 machine I was able to download the package "xfoil 1.1.1": https://pypi.org/project/xfoil/ in Jupyter Notebook by executing the command "!pip install xfoil". I tried doing the exact same thing on my new desktop and get the error "ERROR: Failed building wheel for xfoil" as well as the warning "UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'zip_save'". This is the same error described here: https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/27038/ even though I have no issues installing other packages. The conclusion from that thread seemed to be that the package must have an error associated with it, but I am not sure why it would work on one machine but not the other since I am using Anaconda 3.8 for both.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Using links for reference is great, however your question needs to be complete without them. So include all relevant parts here as well.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug in the package: [`zip_save`](https://github.com/daniel-de-vries/xfoil-python/blob/5c8c4ff62d1b9db03f3b8711f38941cd411ae892/setup.py#L149) is misspelled, it must be spelled `zip_safe`. You cannot do much with it until the author(s) fix the bug.

You can fork the repository, fix the misspelling and install the package from your own repository.

Answer (score 0):

Download the files from [here](https://github.com/daniel-de-vries/xfoil-python).

On your command line type: python setup.py install

If you get this error:

> ValueError: Unknown MS Compiler version 1927

go to

> C:\Python39\Lib\distutils

and locate the file: `cygwinccompiler.py`

In the function

> def get_msvcr():

add one more "elif" statement like this one:

```
elif msc_ver == '1927':
    return ["mspdb140.dll"]
```